# How can I get first elements of arrays in SQL column?

Tags: sql, arrays

I have one SQL column (named COL) with text type and value format as a matrix of multiple arrays (multi-dimensional) as format below:

`[{"par1":val1a,"par2":val2a,...},{"par1":val1b,"par2":val2b,...},{...},{...}]`

In my case, I have the following example (for this, I used 2 dimensions only):

```
{"LineId":701,"StartAllContexts":false,"StartContexts":[8]},{"LineId":700,"StartAllContexts":false,"StartContexts":[8]}]
```

How can I get "LineId" element of each array. So, my result should be something like this:

```
| ID |            COL           |
---------------------------------
|  1 | "LineId":701,"LineId":700 |
```

After "extracting" the elements above, how we can extract the numbers out of it again like below:

```
| ID |   COL   |
----------------
|  1 | 700,701 |
```

Comment: What kind of DBMS do you use?

Comment: You want a query or you want to do it with java?

Comment: Do you have the option to recreate your tables so you don't store arrays in columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server i would like to use of `xml` node method with help of string functions (i.e. `substring()`, `charindex()`, etc..)

```
;with cte as
(
          select 
             m.id, a.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') [col] from 
       (
          SELECT ID, CAST('<m>'+REPLACE(CAST(COL as nvarchar(max)), ',', '</m><m>')+'</m>' as xml) as [col] FROM <table>
       ) m cross apply col.nodes ('/m') as split(a) where a.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') like '%LineId%'
), cte1 as
(
    select id, REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(col), 1, CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(col))-1)) [col] from cte
)
select 
       id,
       col = STUFF(
                    (select ','+[col] from cte1 where id = c1.id ORDER BY [col] for xml path('')),
                    1,1,''
                )
        from cte1 c1 group by c1.id
```

Result :

```
id  col
1   700, 701
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This version of query is exactly what I need.